# Connecting to another server with ArcSDE?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, connection

How to connect from my server in our office to another server in another office with internet and access to their geodatabase by use of ArcSDE?

Comment: [Follow this guideline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for your [questions with answers you like](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2038/gislove)

Answer (score 2):

You need more than just an internet connection.

1. if there are published ArcGIS Server (AGS) layers you would have access to whatever is website.
2. if you have network access you would need the connection string.

With AGS you have wms, wfs, and geodata services that can be consumed over the web.
As far as sde you would need vpn, or some other direct access to the network.

The internet doesn't get you any closer to arcsde.